# Ubuntu 16.04 not getting dhcp lease

Tags: ubuntu, dhcp

I have a brand new ubuntu 16.04 image that I've created with [packer](https://www.packer.io/) based on the [bento configs](https://github.com/chef/bento/blob/master/ubuntu-16.04-amd64.json). My config is nearly identical to the [16.04 config here](https://github.com/chef/bento/blob/master/ubuntu-16.04-amd64.json)

My ubuntu vm fails to get a dhcp lease, even after rebooting. Other windows and centos VMs on the same vlan get their dhcp leases no problem.

The only way I get a lease is if I manually run `dhclient`

/etc/network/interfaces

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto ens32
iface ens32 inet dhcp
pre-up sleep 2
```

When I check `cat /var/log/syslog | grep -Ei 'dhcp'`, I see the dhcp client starting. Strangely it is requesting an IP in the 172.16.x.x network ( I'd expect a 10.x.x.x IP).

```
Dec  2 21:17:02 vagrant dhclient[688]: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.3.3
Dec  2 21:17:02 vagrant sh[676]: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.3.3
Dec  2 21:17:02 vagrant dhclient[688]: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
Dec  2 21:17:02 vagrant sh[676]: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
Dec  2 21:17:02 vagrant dhclient[688]: DHCPDISCOVER on ens32 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x76d9e602)
Dec  2 21:17:02 vagrant sh[676]: DHCPDISCOVER on ens32 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x76d9e602)
Dec  2 21:17:03 vagrant dhclient[688]: DHCPREQUEST of 172.16.148.140 on ens32 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x2e6d976)
Dec  2 21:17:03 vagrant sh[676]: DHCPREQUEST of 172.16.148.140 on ens32 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x2e6d976)
Dec  2 21:17:03 vagrant sh[676]: DHCPOFFER of 172.16.148.140 from 172.16.148.254
Dec  2 21:17:03 vagrant dhclient[688]: DHCPOFFER of 172.16.148.140 from 172.16.148.254
Dec  2 21:17:03 vagrant dhclient[688]: DHCPACK of 172.16.148.140 from 172.16.148.254
Dec  2 21:17:03 vagrant sh[676]: DHCPACK of 172.16.148.140 from 172.16.148.254
Jan  5 16:53:56 vagrant kernel: [    6.068252] audit: type=1400 audit(1483635236.420:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=951 comm="apparmor_parser"
Jan  5 16:53:56 vagrant kernel: [    6.068256] audit: type=1400 audit(1483635236.420:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper" pid=951 comm="apparmor_parser"
Jan  5 16:53:58 vagrant dhclient[1115]: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.3.3
Jan  5 16:53:58 vagrant ifup[965]: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.3.3
Jan  5 16:53:58 vagrant ifup[965]: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
Jan  5 16:53:58 vagrant dhclient[1115]: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
```

Looking at `cat /var/log/syslog | grep network` I see it failed to start the network interface.

```
vagrant@vagrant:~$ cat /var/log/syslog | grep network
Dec  2 21:14:06 vagrant systemd[1]: Strating Raise network interfaces...
Dec  2 21:14:06 vagrant systemd[1]: Started Trigger resolvconf update for networkd DNS.
Dec  2 21:14:06 vagrant ifup[2794]: /sbin/ifup: waiting for lock on /run/network/ifstate.ens32
Dec  2 21:14:07 vagrant systemd[1]: Started Raise network interfaces.
Dec  2 21:15:54 vagrant systemd[1]: Started Trigger resolvconf update for networkd DNS.
Dec  2 21:17:02 vagrant systemd[1]: Starting Raise network interfaces...
Dec  2 21:17:02 vagrant systemd[1]: Started Trigger resolvconf update for networkd DNS.
Dec  2 21:17:02 vagrant ifup[724]: /sbin/ifup: waiting for lock on /run/network/ifstate.ens32
Dec  2 21:17:03 vagrant systemd[1]: Started Raise network interfaces.
Jan  5 16:53:56 vagrant systemd[1]: Started Trigger resolvconf update for networkd DNS.
Jan  5 16:53:58 vagrant systemd[1]: networking.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan  5 16:53:58 vagrant systemd[1]: networking.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jan  5 16:53:58 vagrant systemd[1]: networking.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

From my research that can happen when upgrading ubuntu from 14.04 and 16.04 and the network interfaces don't get renamed properly from the legacy `eth0` to the modern `ens32`. Since this is a brand new ubuntu install, that seems unlikely. Since I can simply run `dhclient` to fix the problem, it seems my interface *is* initialized.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/758594/no-networking-failed-to-bring-up-eth0

Where else can I look to find why the networking interface fails to initialize.
Why would dhcpclient not be running automatically?

**Update**

Running the following gets the network device up, but still no automatic dhcp lease

```
root@vagrant:~# ip link set ens3 up
root@vagrant:~# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:0f:a4:c0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fe0f:a4c0/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

**Update**

The 172.x.x.x ip address showing up in the logs was from december 2nd. This was when the image was built on vmware.

Comment: How is it not getting a lease?  Your screen shot shows it requesting, receiving, and acknowledging 172.16.148.140 .   [eta]: ok, next screen shot shows problem with interface coming up, but that doesn't match the current title of the question.

Comment: Yes, but this is a 10.x network. I have no idea where 172.16.x.x is coming from.

Comment: I have transcribed the contents of your screenshots for you, but you may want to check for errors in transcription.

Answer (score 1):

## Why do logs show 172.16.x.x network?

The vm was created on vmware (with packer), then migrated to kvm. 
The logs are from before the vm was migrated.

## Why does vm not get an ip address?

When the vm was on vmware, its network adapter was `ens32`
After migrationm, the vm network adapter is now called `ens3`
`/etc/network/interfaces` still references the old `ens32`

This is a side affect of the new '[Predictable Network Interface Names](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/)' that started in Ubuntu 15.10

The short term fix is to edit /etc/network/interfaces. 
The long term automated fix is covered here:

[Predictable Network Interface Names break vm migration](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/335461/how-to-change-network-card-on-ubuntu-16-04)